# Alternative of tab view to handle multiple activities

Tags: android, tabs

I am developing an application. We have implemented the functionality in tab view. But i dont want to implement tab widget. Is there any other way of implementing tabs that would behave like tabs, but should not be tabwidget.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ViewPager view.

http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

It behaves like tabs, but without the header at the top.